# NetBeans running "Validating Tool collection on localhost" forever

Tags: java, gcc, netbeans, g++, clang

I was playing with my NetBeans 8.0.2 and I tried to install the Jira plugin (I don't know what was I think...). The install process (or maybe NetBeans itself) showed an error, but it closed itself before I could even start reading the message. Then I started NetBeans again and it started parsing my projects (which is fine), but it also started doing that "Validating Tool collection on localhost".

That thing is launching 5 or 6 gcc/clang/pty processes and then only way to close NetBeans is to kill all those processes.

I deleted everything Jira-related from the plugins folder and I deleted NetBean's cache, but same thing is happening.

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you check the log? You can also try a "clean" start: rename `~/.netbeans` and try again. You also can run NB from terminal to get any errors.

Comment: I disabled C/C++ for now (since I'm doing PHP currently) and the error stopped, so it's something buggy in there. I don't have any  time right now as I'm in a sprint. Furthermore, I was already considering changing IDE, so this might be just the thing that will push me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

This is reported by me as [NB Bug 253458](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=253458) but I'm not sure your problem is really related to the IDE.

It is true that the IDE is very non-verbose as to why it is hanging and what it is trying to do that takes so long. Enabling logging will not give you much.

However, one trick is to use [MS Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/da-dk/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) (if you are on Windows, that is) to figure out what is going on. On my workstation I get the following:

[image]

Then try to execute the same command as NetBeans is trying to execute from a command prompt.  By doing so I discovered that my MSYS2 installation was faulty. Whatever binary I tried to execute (`bash.exe`, `make.exe`, etc) it would take a couple of minutes just to return and say that it was missing arguments. For now I've reverted to MSYS1 and removed traces of MSYS2 from my harddisk and from `PATH`. That works for now. (I don't need MSYS2 as such)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is helpful for this issue but I solved a very similar issue on linux by by uninstalling hardening-wrapper from my archlinux installation.